# comprehensive retry schedule with different time intervals in Airflow

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

i need to implement a comprehensive retry schedule in Airflow, say 3x with 5min interval and then 4x with 2h interval. what is the best way to do so? i am thinking to run the same task with the second retry schedule from on failure callback of the task with the first retry schedule, but the problem is that in that case i cannot (or don't know how) to make downstream task(s) depend on the task executed from callback *only* if it was started in the first place. maybe my idea is totally wrong. any advice?